# How to avoid cumbersome if/else constructs? [Something more like an architecture approach, not just switch statement]

Tags: swift, architecture

I faced a task when I need to process a bunch of conditions and perform an action in the result. Are there any libraries or approaches that can help me building a structure like this? With replaceable/amendable conditions and results?

Comment: You will have to be more specific, I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several patterns here, you can use [Chain Of Responsibility](http://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html) to extract out the logic into separate classes.

If you want to fully extract it, there are rules engines that can help with that, making the if/else more data-driven.  This has it's own concerns, namely around testing, promotion, etc...

Feel free to peruse my rant against rules engines:  [Method or pattern to implement a Business Rules Engine in a solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706399/method-or-pattern-to-implement-a-business-rules-engine-in-a-solution/29709449#29709449)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think this is what I have searched for